# List comprehension- fill arbitrary value if list is empty

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am using a list comprehension to assign values to an object. In short, I have two lists. One which contains a collection of values and another which contains a collection of indices (from that previous list)

```
values = [1.4,1.5,1.6,1.8]
indices = [0,1]
a.newvalues = [values[i] for i in indices]
```

This works fine when indices isn't empty. However, when indices is empty I would like an arbitrary value (-1) to be assigned to `newvalues`, instead of returning an empty list.

Can anyone think of a way?

Comment: I think it would be better to keep you code like here to maintain  len(a) == len (indices) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

```
values = [1.4,1.5,1.6,1.8]
indices = [0,1]
a.newvalues = [values[i] for i in indices] if indices else [-1]
```

I'm not sure I follow. When indices is empty, `a.newvalues` should take the value -1, not a list of some length?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been clearer. Ideally when indices is empty, a.newvalues should take the value [-1] 
Your suggestion above works for me when I enclose [] around -1

Comment: As a complement, assume I have a function in place of indices, would the evaluation be lazy here? For example `[values[i] for i in indices()] if indices() else [-1]`. Would indices be evaluated once or twice?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check for indices length:

```
if len(indices):
    a.values = [values[i] for i in indices]
else:
    a.values = -1
```

Comment: You don't need to pull `len()`, you can just do `if indices:`.  `bool([]) == False`

Answer (score 1):

And I want to add lambda style

```
sorted(map(lambda x: values[x], indices)) if indices else [-1]
```

Comment: This will produce `[]` if indices is empty, not -1 or [-1] or anything like that.